# get previous or next cell value of table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i get appointment time (From time,To time) in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168382/how-i-get-appointment-time-from-time-to-time-in-jquery)

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrW2n/9/)

i am selecting time slot by dragging on time slot cell.
   after selecting time slot i enter name in textbox then patient appointment is allotted for that time slot.
                    i have to insert patient name like(abc),start time like(8:00AM  0) and end time like(8:00AM  30) in database.
                    how can i get these three values in jquery.

Comment: You should be more detailed in your questions. You asked how to get some values, then complained when the selection code that you had that wasn't working was ignored, and people tried to give you solutions to the question that you did ask. This took time and effort try to help you!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is a lot of work to make the timetable look great and give a good user experience on various browsers. 
Maybe you could use the jQuery full calendar ( http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and customize it to fit your needs.

Here is a demo for creating time events on a single day:

http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/selectable.html

Comment: u didnt get my quetion see in my fiddle if i drag time from 8:00 AM 0 to 30 then i type some name in textbox and click on update button
    then textbox value goes to alloted time slot so my quetion is how can i get those values in jquery variable for further operation.

Comment: Sorry, but I consider that in the current situation it is no easy solution to select the time without either changing the HTML or trying to parse the values in the cells, compare them and extract the time interval. That is why I suggested using a widget specialized that would solve the problems you are having now and possibly future issues.

Answer (score -1):

Use the new [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5) `time` element ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/time)). Then it is easy to fetch the time with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Here is a complete example on how to fetch the first selected cell, and the last selected cell. Do the selection after the user has clicked the update button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script 
        src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script 
        src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var start = $("td.csstdhighlight:first > time").attr("datetime");
            var end = $("td.csstdhighlight:last > time").attr("datetime");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td class="csstdhighlight">
            <time datetime="2000-01-01 08:00:00">00</time>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="csstdhighlight">
            <time datetime="2000-01-01 08:15:00">15</time>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="csstdhighlight">
            <time datetime="2000-01-01 08:30:00">30</time>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><time datetime="2000-01-01 08:45:00">45</time></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if you want to support Internet Explorer 8 or below you need to make sure that IE treats the new HTML5 `time` element as supposed to. The easiest option is to include the [Modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/) as in the sample above, or if you want the details you can read the blog post  [How to get HTML5 working in IE and Firefox 2](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/).

Comment: And why does that matter? Works in any browser with a one liner JavaScript hack, or by including the [Modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: u didnt get my quetion see in my fiddle if i drag time from 8:00 AM 0 to 30 then i type some name in textbox and click on update button
   then textbox value goes to alloted time slot so my quetion is how can i get those values in jquery variable for further operation.

Comment: In my answer I tell you how you may use the new HTML5 semantic element `time` to mark up your HTML so that you may use jQuery to fetch the start and end time of the appointment. You allready know the name. It lives in the text box.

Comment: did u get my quetion and i dnt use html 5 the value in time slot cell is dynamic not static

Answer (score -1):

With some slight html modifications such as adding a class to the time cells and some data attributes, you can take advantage of `jQuery.data()` and use classes to simplify locating cells

```
 <td class="csstablelisttd time" data-hour="9" data-minute="45"> 45 </td>
```

When a "slot" has been booked, add a class to it that identifies it is booked. Storing the name of the patient to the time cell as data allows you to then do something like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var msg = 'No Bookings',
        $booked = $('.booked');
    if ($booked.length) {
        msg = [];
        $booked.each(function() {          
            var data = $(this).data()
            msg.push(data.hour + ':' + data.minute + ' - ' + data.patient)
        })
        msg = msg.join('\n');
    }
    alert(msg)
})
```

Here is a much simplifed, but working version using click event on the time cell. Your mouse selection method didn;t seem to work and a click is more user friendly. This won't complete your whole app, but should give you some ideas going forward

http://jsfiddle.net/vrW2n/27/

Comment: charlietfl soln is fine but time slot have to select by dragging more than one cell

Comment: use jQuery UI selectable. You can still use pretty much the same code , just add same class to all selected. What you had was not working, and your question was about how to get the values. You have along way to go from this simple mock up to having html that will do what you want

Comment: with current jquery code is not possible

Comment: u use use html 5 in ur fiddle i dnt use html 5

Comment: I did not use html 5, `data-` attributes work in html4