# How i get appointment time (From time,To time) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am selecting time slot on dragging on time slot cell. After selecting time slot, I enter patient name in textbox and click on select button then patient name goes to selected time slot. The user can select multiple time slot for multilpe patient name and onclick of allot button I have to insert patient name with time slot (From time To time) to database.

I have problem in getting alloted time slot ie.From time and To time in jquery.

```
$("#btnAllot").click(function () {
    //how i get alloted time here.
    $('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('yell')) {
                alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());

            };
        });
    });
}
```

[see jsbin on dragging on time slot cell](http://jsbin.com/udimuq/edit#javascript,html,live)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is one way to do it:

You iterate over each row whose third cell has a `rowspan` attribute. This indicates the start of a new appointment. You can get the start time by examining the siblings (sort of) and the end time by getting the row that is `rowspan - 1` elements away.

There might be better ways, but this might give you a start.

For example:

```
var find_closest_hour = function($row) {
    var $cell = $row.children('td:first-child'),
        hour = "";
    // probably add something here
    while($cell.length && !(hour = $.trim($cell.text()))) {
        $cell = $cell.parent().prev().children('td:first-child');
    }
    return hour;
};

var $all_tds = $('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)'),
    $tds = $all_tds.filter('[rowspan]'); 

// will contain a list of objects [{patient: name, start: time, end: time},...]
var appointments = $tds.map(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $row = $this.parent(),
        $cells =  $row.children('td'),
        patient = $.trim($this.text()),
        start = find_closest_hour($row).split(':', 1) + ":" + $.trim($cells.eq(1).text()),
        $end_row, end;

    if(this.rowspan == 1) {
        end = start;
    }
    else {
        $end_row = $all_tds.eq($all_tds.index(this) + this.rowSpan - 1).parent();
        end = find_closest_hour($end_row).split(':', 1) + ":" + $.trim($end_row.children('td').eq(1).text());
    }

    return {patient: patient, start: start, end: end};
}).get();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/udimuq/4/edit)

I will let you figure out how to format the times properly ;)

**Note:** This very much depends on your current table structure and is likely to break if you change it. To make things more flexible, you could add classes to cells that contain the important information, for example `hour` to each first cell that contains the hour of the day and `appointment_start` to the cell of an appointment. Then you could search for/filter by these.

Comment: in js bin its not working and again i chk in my page getting   alert(appointments);(object object object object)

Comment: It is working, have a look at the **console**. That the alert shows `object` three times is correct, if you have created three appointments.

Comment: In IE console is undefined and in mozilla doesnt show anything on click of allot button

Comment: Well yes, IE does not have `console` but in Firefox, I can see the output in the web console... Believe me, I tested the code, `appointments` contains a list of objects, do something with it. Maybe you like this output more: http://jsbin.com/udimuq/5/edit

Comment: In IE $('body').append(JSON.stringify(appointments)); not working but in firefox  json working what i do for ie

Comment: I only used that line to show you the structure of `appointments`. You should not used it at all! It is an **example**. You can do whatever you want with the data in `appointments`, e.g. create an HTML list from it, send to the server to store it in a DB, etc. Your question was how to extract the information from the table and I presented a possible solution. Now do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: thanks for ur reply anyway i will found out why in IE showing object instead of data....Thanks Felix  I appreciate for your answer +++

Comment: Felix in IE now it showing i have select only one row ie 8:00AM 0 showing me result whole table values   [{"patient":"Patient Name","start":":Time Slot","end":":Time Slot"},{"patient":"","start":"8:0","end":"8:0"},{"patient":"","start":"8:15","end":"8:15"},{"patient":"","start":"8:30","end":"8:30"},{"patient":"","start":"8:45","end":"8:45"},{"patient":"","start":"9:0","end":"9:0"},{"patient":"","start":"9:15","end":"9:15"},{"patient":"","start":"9:30","end":"9:30"},{"patient":"","start":"9:45","end":"9:45"}]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm working with Mac OS X, I cannot test it in IE. Maybe it has something to do with the `rowspan` attribute... you could try adding a class instead to the first selected cell and filter the cells by that class, like I described in my answer.